Using a dual-gate mosfet as a replacement for a single-gate mosfet, can the additional gate be left floating?
Trying to replace an obsolete single-gate mosfet(MPF157) with a dual-gate mosfet(MFE3004) with similar characteristics. This is used in an RF preamplifier of an HF receiver. Can the additional gate be left floating?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You should bias up the second gate of the proposed replacement device.it should not be left floating. If you ground it there will not be any drain current   .3VDC is a rough guess but check the specs to ensure a sensible drain current .Remember that the dual gate device can be roughly thought of as a cascode pair of jfets.

Could you short both of the gates and then treat them as a single gate?
